# Find the values ​​of $\alpha$ and $\beta$ for which $x' = at^{\alpha}+bx^{\beta}$ becomes an equation homogenously

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Find the values ​​of $\alpha$ and $\beta$ for which $$x' = at^{\alpha}+bx^{\beta}$$ 
becomes an equation homogenously through a change of variables of the form $x = y^m$

Comment: Well, what equation did you get after the change of variables?

Comment: Did the replacement but can not eliminate the first term.